# Will mapping a network drive prevent the computer from sleeping?

Tags: networking, network-shares, sleep, shared-folders

I have a media computer that I want to go to sleep when it's not being used. Trying to be green to my wallet. But it seems like since I've done the network mapping, that it doesn't go to sleep.

Before I had it setup so if the Media Server was a sleep, that a network request could wake it up, so I'm wondering if mapping the hard drives pings the Media Server or something else to prevent it from sleeping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, mapping a drive will not prevent a computer from entering sleep mode. I have well over 20 network drives mapped on some systems.

Things to check:

- Power settings
- Disable Wake on LAN for your Ethernet adapter (an application you installed may be using this)

Comment: But here is the catch. I want the Media Server to be able to be woken via lan, say if someone tries to open the mapped drive. Just want it to sleep when no one is streaming video or audio.

Comment: Then set the power settings really low, say, 5 minutes and the hard disks should turn off etc @Tyler.

Comment: I have set that on the server and pre-network mapping the server would go to sleep. Now however, it doesn't. Too much Red Bull or something.

Comment: Looking more into Server 2003, it looks like there is a Session being created when my Windows 7 computer connects via mapped network that doesn't get closed when not being used.